# How to separate out part of a string based on a pattern in typescript (probably using regex)

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I have a string like this: `This is a string [img https://url.com/img.jpg]`

I want to take the string and separate out just the URL by searching for the "[img ]" pattern and taking the text within that (i.e. in the above, just the https://url.com/img.jpg)

Is there a way to do this with regular expressions? The "[]" are throwing me off on how to write one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is escape it with `\`. Like this:

```js
const str = "This is a string [img https://url.com/img.jpg]"

const url = str.match(/\[img ([^\]]+)\]/)[1];
console.log(url); // => https://url.com/img.jpg
```